# Mysql - Search for a word in json text and only give back a result if it occurs in more rows

Tags: mysql, search, count

Hy i want to search for a word in my table but i only want a result if the word occurred in more then 3 rows.

So basically my query is this, which partially works:

```
SELECT *
FROM  `someTable` 
WHERE  `field_A` LIKE  '%wordToFind%'
OR  `field_B` LIKE  '%wordToFind%'
```

This works just fine, in the result i will see all the rows that matched the query.

So the problem is it will return all the matched rows, for example if only one row was matched it will return only one, but i want this query to be limited to at least 5.

By that i mean i only want a returned result if the query match at least 5 fields.

I hope i was clear, thank you.

Comment: That puts a maximum, he wants to set a minimum.

Comment: Can you give example with data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM  `someTable` 
WHERE  (`field_A` LIKE  '%wordToFind%'
        OR  `field_B` LIKE  '%wordToFind%')
AND (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM  `someTable` 
     WHERE  (`field_A` LIKE  '%wordToFind%'
             OR `field_B` LIKE  '%wordToFind%')) >= 5
```

This might not be very efficient, as it may search for the rows twice, first for the subquery and then for the main query.

Comment: allready tried that one, and its not working, because it will return me a result even if there are 2 matches

Comment: Needed parentheses because of precedence between `AND` and `OR`. Try now.